# Connecting Firebird to an ASP.net WebAPI Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, firebird

I'm in the process of learning ASP.net, specifically WebAPI and MVC. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013, .NET 4.5, and C#. I'm a total newb so I'm actually going through this particular walkthrough to understand how things work:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

It's been ok so far, but I want to move on to connecting a database to populate my dataset. I'm very familiar with using Firebird and was able to install Firebird as a dataprovider (through NuGet and installing the appropriate DDEX files). Unfortunately, I'm having difficulty understanding how to query the database and populate my array.

Basically, this is what my code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;

namespace NBAPoolWebService.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {

        User[] users = new User[] 
        {
            new User { ID = 1, CREATED=new DateTime(2011, 1, 12), ISACTIVE='Y', USERNAME="TEST1"}, 
            new User { ID = 2, CREATED=new DateTime(2012, 2, 22), ISACTIVE='Y', USERNAME="TEST2"}

        };

        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return users;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int id)
        {
            var user = users.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.ID == id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, if I visit http://localhost/api/user, I get my list of test users via JSON (which is what I want).

What I'm hoping to understand is how to change the array that I set to come from my Firebird database (via an SQL query). I know how to get my query (select * from users), I have a valid connection (confirmed through visual studio) and I have seen some tutorials on how to use FBConnection.

What I'm having difficulty with is actually using the data from the query and populate the objects in the array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you could tell me the piece of code that I need to enter, or point me to the right tutorials, or if you think I should be using a specific technology or methodology, that would be great.

What I'm trying really trying to accomplish/understand is how to create a Web service that responds with JSON and that is connected to a Firebird database.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You first need to install the Firebird connector for Dotnet https://www.ibphoenix.com/download/connectivity/dotnet and then you can use appropriate connection string to query your database as if it where a mysql/access/sqlite etc. via nuget PM> Install-Package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient

Comment: Thanks Bellash, I did the following installations on my computer: [link]http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/4.6.1/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient-4.6.1.0.msi/download [link]http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/DDEX%203.0.1/DDEXProvider-3.0.1.0.msi/download and I also searched NuGet and added Entity Framework, FB ADO.net provider, and FB Entity Framework Provider through the Visual Nuget Manager. What I'm really hoping to get is the syntax to query the database and pass that info into my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned a ton about .Net and Entity Framework by watching pluralsight videos.  If you don't have an account with them, signing up for the trial would allow you to watch [Entity Framework and Data Models](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/efintro-models).  There is a module dedicated to Creating Database First Entity Data Models, which you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks Sherri, I saw the comments from you husband regarding the issue you ran into and it looks like you were able to get things going so I won't respond. I actually had the exact same issue but my project was local. After a whole whack of debugging my existing project, I just ended up starting a new one after basically removing & reinstalling all of the required components. Which then resulted in my FB connection window disappearing. This required me fixing my machine.config (google it). I realize this comment is long winded and not applicable to you , just hoping to help others out there.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of research, I stumbled upon the following link:

[link]http://johntomaselli.blogspot.ca/2012/04/mvc-4-firebird-ef-41-and-database-first.html

So I deleted my existing User Controller and Model and created a new Model using ADO.NET Entity Data Model (named User).

From there, I used EF Designed from Database and used the connectionstring I created in my web.config.

From there it let me choose the database tables I wanted and built out a Model called User.edmx.

After that, I created a controller using Web API2 Controller with action, using Entity Framework.

This allowed me to choose a model class with the corresponding name.

At this point, I think I need to do some research on the Entity Framework but this at least allows me to create a web service that connects to the database.

Hopefully this helps other young newbs on their start with ASP.net, MVC, WebAPI, Entity Frameworks, and Firebird.

My next steps will be understand the User.edmx and if I should have created a model for all tables (instead of just one). Hopefully I understand that when I resarch the Entity Framework.

Comment: My wife finds herself in a nearly exact situation as your original question, but hasn't managed to solve it, even given your answer here.  But she doesn't have enough SO reputation yet to post this comment herself, so I'm helping her out:

Comment: "I had pretty much given up getting firebird to work with entity framework 6 in VS 2013 until I saw this answer.  You mention that you "created a new Model using ADO.NET Entity Data Model”, which is where I’m getting stuck.  I think I’ve done the same setup as you mention in the comments of your question, but I’m obviously missing something.  Would you mind taking a look at my question http://goo.gl/I2Kttl to see if you notice anything that I can do different to get past my issue?  Thanks!"